# How to separate between Unsubscribe confirmation page and Subscription confirmation page?

Tags: exm

On a manager root in EXM (9.0.1), the "Final Confirmation Page" is used for *both* subscription confirmation (after a subscribed user clicks the "confirm" link in the confirmation email), as well as unsubscribe confirmation (after a subscribed user clicks the "unsubscribe" link in an email campaign).

How am I to separate the two and fulfill our requirement of having a unique message for subscription versus unsubscribe confirmation? Or am I forced to use a generic message like "Your subscription preferences have been updated"? The documentation is really not clear on this.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to create your own custom ConfirmSubscription.aspx or Unsubscribe.aspx/UnsubscribeFromAll.aspx page, and replace the default ones in the /sitecore modules/Web/EXM/ folder on the CD role.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am unable to figure out how to figure out if the user has subscribed or unsubscribed.