# Email Root Manager - Final Confirmation Page

Tags: exm

Sitecore 9.0.2 EXM manager root has the following field

**Final Confirmation Page - The page displayed after a visitor changes their subscription:**

I am unable to understand how this actually works. I have tried it with the 'Unsubscribe from All' link in email footer and I was getting redirected it to the page configured in this field.

[How to separate between Unsubscribe confirmation page and Subscription confirmation page?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11356/how-to-separate-between-unsubscribe-confirmation-page-and-subscription-confirmat)  confirms that it happens when the user subscribes also. Please help me to understand as how this functionality works and how this gets triggered.

I have seen the documentation related to it but did not find any details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXM provide two mechanism for unsubscribing: **Unsubscribe link** and **unsubscribe from all**

@Pete Navarra describes in details this functionality :

https://sitecorehacker.com/2018/12/17/managing-the-unsubscribe-part-1

**Unsubscribe link**

When this link is clicked out of an email, Sitecore will process the Redirect URL and redirect to the Unsubscribe linked above. This page has no styling and no layout. It will actually just return blank if it succeeds correctly. But there’s actually magic happening behind the scenes

**1. The Contact is Removed From Contact List**
The Unsubscribe Link is specific to a single message, which is tied to specific Manager Root. When this link is clicked, Sitecore EXM will search for the first Contact List in the Inclusion List on the email and attempt to remove the user from it.

If ONLY Segmented Lists are used on the message or the contact can NOT be found on the first list, then to prevent accidentally sending this contact a message again, this user is added to the Global Opt-Out List defined on the Manager Root.

**2. The Contact is redirected to the Final Confirmation Page**
On the Manager Root under Subscription Control there is a field for Final Confirmation Page that the Contact/visitor is redirected to when the unsubscribe completes successfully.

**3. If contact is already unsubscribed, redirected to Already Unsubscribed**
If the contact has already unsubscribed (maybe they clicked on the Unsubscribe Link in their email a second time) then Sitecore will redirect the contact to the Already Unsubscribed page/item. This is helpful, because it could provide the user the ability to resubscribe.

**Unsubscribe From All**

This is a full unsubscribe from all messages being sent from a selected Manager Root. The Manager Root is identified because the query parameters going into this link provide the Message ID, which is needed to know which Manager Root to use.

If you recall from our Introduction to the Manager Root, there is a field that specifies the Global Opt-Out List. This List Manager Contact List, is evaluated every time an email is dispatched (automated or regular). If the contact exists in this list, they will be automatically excluded from the delivery of the message.

Processing the Unsubscribe From All URL performs the following actions.

**1. The Contact is Added to the Global Opt-Out List**

The contact is immediately added to the Global Opt-Out List. They are NOT removed from the first Contact List on the message, as described above.

**2. The Contact is redirected to the Final Confirmation Page**

On the Manager Root under Subscription Control there is a field for Final Confirmation Page that the Contact/visitor is redirected to when the unsubscribe completes successfully.

Out of the box, this field is blank. However, by specifying it to a branded page on your website, the Unsubscribe link will redirect the user to here.

**3. If contact is already unsubscribed, redirected to Already Unsubscribed**
If the contact has already unsubscribed (maybe they clicked on the Unsubscribe Link in their email a second time) then Sitecore will redirect the contact to the Already Unsubscribed page/item. This is helpful, because it could provide the user the ability to resubscribe.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail. Please help me to understand the flow during sign-in.

Comment: Signin functionality should be in other question. Please do not add other question/ requirements in comments. If it helps my answer please mark it at right answer and and add other question for signin.